# Java JMX Remote Connection

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, remote-server, jvisualvm

I work with Java 1.6  and I want to connect my remote Jboss 7 server and monitoring it.

I have already added parameters in `.../bin/stabdalone.conf` file

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=18189"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

but I get error

```
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Can anybody help me?